# Can resources from MS Visual Studio be used with Eclipse & Cygwin?

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio, cygwin

I'm a noob with C++, but I need to resolve this problem ASAP.
I'm trying to run some C++ examples in Eclipse with Cygwin toolchain. These examples use functions like wcsncpy_s (in string.h or wchar.h). 
The problem is that I can only use MS Visual Studio to compile these examples: wcsncpy_s is marked as "undeclared" even if string.h or wchar.h are included.

Is there a way to use cygwin with Eclipse and also use resources (libraries I believe) from Microsoft (like those mentioned above)? Maybe I just need to update Cygwin? Or is there no solution for this ?
Please advice :)

Comment: FYI: *MSDN* is the *Microsoft Developers Network* and has nothing to do with the issue. Also, welcome to SO :)

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I meant Microsoft Visual Studio (MS VS). I was in a hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wcsncpy_s` is not a standard C or C++ library function (note: I think they may have added similar function in C11, but I'm not sure). It is a function Microsoft added to their standard libraries in Visual Studio.

It's not a bad function, for what it does. But it's non-standard. And they don't use the usual leading underscore to indicate that it's non-standard.

Comment: So, you are saying that my only option is to use Visual Studio ? (these examples use an API that consists of about 30 .h files and 2 .dll files and use functions like wcsncpy_s in many places)

Comment: @ice13ill: Is there some reason why you need to copy those examples *exactly*? They're just example code. You're supposed to learn from it, not copy-and-paste it into your files.

Comment: Functions like wcsncpy_s are used by the API (in the .h files). When I try to compile with eclipse I get errors referencing to lines of code inside those files (the API .h files).

Comment: Maybe there are some settings that I need to modify in eclipse ?(project properties). I created a default project and I just copied the api files and examples.

Comment: @ice13ill: I'm not sure how much more clearly I can say this. Those are *Microsoft-specific* functions. They are part of *Microsoft's* libraries. They are *not part of C++!* You can only use them with Visual Studio. It's that simple. It is not a standard function, so you're not going to get it to work in other compilers.

Comment: I thought that those libraries could be also used with Eclipse somehow. I just needed to be sure.